# Select the active object ? with python

Tags: scripting

[image]

i just want to select this object, the suzanne with the active origin in red,'is is she active or just the last selected?

i dont know the code, and i dont know also how to find this kind of code, ive been searching for two hours... any tips how to find the desired action within blender in this kind of cases?

thanks

Comment: bpy.context.active_object [related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124014/blender-2-8-python-active-removed-from-api-how-to-pick-active-object-now#comment216466_124014)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38618/selecting-an-object-via-scripting/38626?s=16|10.1725#38626

Comment: Please show the entire screen with footers so we all the information needed

Comment: bpy.context.active_object dont work for me on 2.8

Comment: i also tried

bpy.context.active_object.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.active_object

i got error 
and i dont know what im doing im just trying to copy code that work on the proposed lonk, but it doesnt result in anything

Comment: i also tried this, not working either "ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.select = True"

Answer (score 1):

You can usually retrieve the active object with: `bpy.context.active_object` or `bpy.context.object`

If you need to take the view layer into account: `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active`

Chances are your view layer is already set, but if the view layer needs to be set, you can first do: `bpy.context.window.view_layer = view_layer`

<sup>[[source]](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-get-the-active-layer/12265)</sup>

To make sure the active object is also a selected object, you can do this:

```
import bpy
my_object = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active # assign variable
my_object.select_set(True) # select the object
```

*Setting* an object as active is a similar process. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38618/) to learn about that.

Many operations require both an active object and *at least one additional* selected object.